# onPictureTaken byte[] small size in some device

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap

I Creating custom camera app i am using Surfaceview. In my app i capture the picture  but it work perfectly in Note 4 and it problematic in xiaomi mobile and  i don't the reason why this happen.

**Note 4 onPictureTaken Byte[] size is original.**

BUT

**xiaomi onPictureTaken Byte[] size is always 160x120**

Here is my code

```
     PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            final BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//                sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                sizeOptions.inScaled = false;
//                sizeOptions.inDither = false;
            sizeOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, sizeOptions);
            Log.d("onPictureTaken", "Bitmap is " + sizeOptions.outWidth + "x"
                    + sizeOptions.outHeight);


            int angleToRotate = getRoatationAngle(currentCameraId);
            Log.d("Tag", "Rotation angle: " + angleToRotate);
            if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                angleToRotate = angleToRotate + 180;

            final String albumId = Util.ReadSharePrefrence(getActivity(), Constant.SHRED_PR.KEY_Current_AlbumID);
            new SavePhotoTask(albumId, data, angleToRotate, isChecked, orientation).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I am post question for about 3 hours but no one even commenting.

I figure out whats the problem. It is depending on parameter part [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605560/how-do-you-take-high-resolution-images-using-camera-takepicture/10605793#10605793)

Here is my code

```
 private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
        if (camera != null && previewHolder.getSurface() != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
//              Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback","Exception in setPreviewDisplay()");
            }
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
            parameters.setJpegQuality(90);
            if (size != null) {
                Log.d("", "initPreview: width  = "+size.width+ " height = "+size.height);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                cameraConfigured = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are the values of width and height in the parameters? Is it the desired height and width??

Comment: Arpit Patel: Do you mean the default picture size of xiaomi phones are set to 160x120?